# RxJava emit error on empty

Tags: exception, error-handling, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to "throw" custom error if an `Observable` does not emit exactly one value before completing.

Let me try to show an example:

```
Observable<SomeClass> stream = ...

stream
.filter(...)
.singleOrError(new MyCustomException())
```

So I have a stream of SomeClass objects. I want to emit custom error if `fitler()` does not emit exactly one element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `.singleOrError()` throws `NoSuchElementException` if the source emits no items, you can check instance of thrown exception and return your custom one.

```
    stream.filter(...)
            .singleOrError()
            .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                if (throwable instanceof NoSuchElementException) {
                    return Single.error(new MyCustomException());
                } else {
                    return Single.error(throwable);
                }
            });
```

Note that if the `filter()` emits more than one item, `singleOrError()` will throw `IllegalArgumentException`. This can either be handled in the `onErrorResumeNext()`, or by simply adding `take(1)` before `singleOrError()`.

Comment: Yeap. That works. single().onErrorResumeNext(Single.error(new CustomError())